# How to change background color and font color on click (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on an eReader-like project for school and I was instructed to not to use jQuery.

I want to allow users to change the colors of the page based on their preferences. I figured how to change the `background-color` by using color names in the class of the buttons, but I can't figure how to change the font `color` (something I really need to do specifically for the black background).

Any help would be appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="textBox">Dummy text</div>
<button class="bisque">sepia</button>
<button class="black">black</button>
<button class="white">white</button>
```

JS:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems[i].onclick = function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var color = this.getAttribute('class');
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = color;
   }
};
```

Comment: You say no jQuery, yet you tag the question with jQuery?

Comment: Did you try looking up what `style` property corresponds to text color? (it's just `color`)

Comment: With the existing code I have, it's set to change based off the color name I wrote in the div class (ie - black, white, etc). So I'm not sure how to add font color on top of it.  Also I deleted the jQyery tag. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the font `color` doing the following:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   elems[i].onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var color = this.getAttribute('class');
     var font_color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
     document.getElementsByClassName('textBox')[0].style.color = font_color;
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = color;
   }
};
```

```html
<div class="textBox">Dummy text</div>
<button class="bisque" data-color="black">sepia</button>
<button class="black" data-color="white">black</button>
<button class="white" data-color="bisque">white</button>
```

Comment: Terry, thanks for chiming in! However, I don't want to change the font to the same color as the background since I need it to be readable. I really just need to change the font to white when the black background is set.